# How do I get Apple Photos to sync on macOS?

Tags: photos, data-synchronization

I'm aware that Apple Photos syncs in the background according to it's own rules, but Apple Photos on macOS hasn't synced (according to the status at the bottom of my library) for almost 20 hours, despite my having taken several photos (all of which appear in Photos on my other devices and in iCloud) in the meantime.

What do I need to do to get Apple Photos to sync when I need it to, or at least on a more reasonable schedule?

---

macOS 11.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Apple Photos Preferences has a checkbox labeled My Photostream that should be checked. If it is ALREADY checked, uncheck it and re-check it and things should start up again.